# How to create multiple entities using a single OData POST to a Business Central Web Service?

Tags: rest, odata, dynamics-business-central

I tried to POST an array of objects and, as expected, it isn't that easy. In my case I want to insert multiple *Transfer Order Lines* in the same request.

```json
// Request Body
[
    {
        "documentNo": "1002",
        "itemNo": "1968-S",
        "quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "documentNo": "1002",
        "itemNo": "1968-S",
        "quantity": 113
    }
]

// Response
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid Request Body  CorrelationId:  a2606676-3f8f-4753-aaee-be91a621f070."
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do what I want without sending a request for every *Line* entity I want to add?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a structure like this:

url: api/2.0/$batch

Body:

````
     ```lang-json
            {
             "requests":
             [
             {
            "method": "POST",
            "id":"R1",
            "url": "companies(id)/APIEntitySetName",
            "headers":
            {
            "content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body":
            {}
            },
            {
            another line
            }
            ]
            }
```
````

Comment: You should always format your code so that it is readable.